# iOS Sprite Kit - Distort Body Upon Collision

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody

I am trying to create a surface that will distort upon collision of another object. Imagine a rubber partition that bends outward when shot with a projectile, and then retracts back to it's original (flat) shape

Is there any built-in method of animating a distortion of a body upon collision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You can however implement a soft-body by using multiple bodies connected with (spring) joints. But it will be difficult to make it "keep" its distorted shape.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds perfect. I don't need to retain the distortion, just bounce back to its original shape.